# What is the quickest way to find book authors among SO users?

Tags: discussion, search, books

There are many published authors with high popularity and credence at SO. Is there a way to query or list out all of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:
http://stackql.net/default.aspx?qid=13732

You'll get a lot of false positives (ie: "Author of XXX project"), but there are a lot of actual authors in there.

Comment: Woow..thats a whole bunch of logs...how am I to find the authors?

Comment: Cool! gotcha post edit.

Comment: Unfortunately, the dataset for those queries isn't current, so in addition to the false positives, it also misses some (like me!)

Comment: Won't most people have Amazon links for books they've authored? That would be a good search criterion...

Comment: @Jon: Looking through the results, it's mostly just text.  But I could certainly do an "OR" search to bring in both.

Comment: D'oh!  The query id in the link was off by one :(  fixed now.